# ng-template - how to bind a checkbox to a pair of objects for on/off state

Tags: angularjs

Angular newb here.

I'm trying to set up templates to display a collection of 'questionnaire' items.  The questionnaire items may be a choice list or check box.  Each questionnaire choice has an associated cost with it.

EG:

```
{ "Name" : "Product Packaging", "Template" : "TemplateList",
  "Choices" : [ { "Box", 20 }, { "Tube", 30 } ] },
{ "Name" : "Custom Printing" , "Template" : "TemplateCheckbox",
  "Choices" : [ { true, 10 }, { false, 0 } ] }
```

Templates:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="TemplateList.html">
    <div>{{configitem.Name}}</div>
    <div class="choiceValue">
        <select ng-model="configitem.CurrentChoice" ng-options="choice.Value for choice in configitem.Choices" ng-change="update()">
        </select>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="TemplateCheckbox.html">
    <div>{{configitem.Name}}</div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="configitem.CurrentChoice.Value" ng-change="update()"/>
    </div>
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ConfiguratorCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="configitem in model.ConfigurableItems">
        <div ng-include="configitem.Template + '.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div>Price: {{model.CurrentPrice | currency}}</div>
</div>
```

I'm using templates to display these objects based on the 'Template' type.  This works well.  However, I'd like to figure out a way to indirectly bind to my controller for the checkbox items.  I need the on/off state for the checkbox to bind to one of the true/false 'choice' objects.  Right now, it's binding to the first choice element.  Any suggestions?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CadGuy/mqo9wj1s/2/)

Comment: Your Fiddle isn't showing any output.  Is there any way you can put a working example in Fiddle or Plunker so we can see the output?

Comment: Just updated the fiddle.

Comment: I worked on it a bit but haven't gotten far yet.  I bound the checkbox to a boolean with ngModel, then ttried to pass it back to your configurator to do `if (isChecked === true) { CurrentChoice = cfg3.Choices[0]} else {CurrentChoice = cfg3.Choices[1]}`  It seems like it would work, but can't figure out how to add a $scope dependency to your configurator.  I refactored your configurator as a service, but it still wouldn't accept $scope.